Quasi-invariance of $\Phi_3^4$ under translation by nonsmooth shifts
In https://hairer.org/Phi4.pdf Hairer shows that the $\Phi_3^4$ measure is mutually singular with respect to any nonzero smooth shift. Is it also mutually singular with respect to any nonzero nonsmooth shift?

The argument given there should work up to shifts in $C^{1,\alpha}$ for some (arbitrary) $\alpha > 0$. I don't know about shifts that are rougher than that, but I would be really surprised if it made any difference (as long as the shift is deterministic of course).
